# Python Box API - how to get a single file with the latest upload date in a Box folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, box-api

I'm using box-python-sdk to read files from a Box folder:

```
items = client.folder(folder_id).get_items()
```

Then I create a generator of file items. But from all of these files I only need the one that has a latest upload date. I didn't find a way to achieve this in the [docs](https://github.com/box/box-python-sdk/tree/master/docs/usage).

```
for item in items:
    if item.type == 'file':
        yield StringIO(str(client.file(item.id).content(), 'utf-8'))
```

How can I filter items to get only a single file with the latest upload date in the folder?

Answer (score 1):

To limit the items to just the latest uploaded file in a folder you will need to make the API call and sort the items by date.

https://developer.box.com/reference/get-folders-id-items/#param-sort

This will actually return the latest folders before the latest files, which means you can't just set the limit to 0.

An alternative approach is to listen to the enterprise event feed to listen for an UPLOAD event.

https://developer.box.com/reference/get-events/

Another approach is to use a Box Skill or a webhook on your folder to listen for uploads.

Comment: I'm reading from a single folder by Id and it is guaranteed that it will contain only files. So there will be no need to sort folders.